# How to pattern match on two kind of parameters in action with phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to match two kind of parameter set.
If params come from out of IndexController, receive main_id only.
But if params come from same page with `index_path(@conn, :index, main_id)` and select box value.

*IndexController.ex*

```
defmodule IndexController do
  def index(conn, %{"main_id" => main_id, "sub_id" => sub_id}) do
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end
```

*index.html.eex*

```
<%= form_for @conn, index_path(@conn, :index, main_id), fn f -> %>
  <%= select f, :sub_id, Enum.map(@items, &{&1.item_name, &1.id}) %>
<% end %>
```

How can I write router.ex match with two kind of parameter set?

```
get "/index/:main_id", IndexController, :index
post "/index/:main_id/:sub_id", IndexController, :index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you would need to handle optional parameters and this is the way I would go about doing that:

```
defmodule IndexController do
  def index(conn, %{"main_id" => main_id} = params) do
    # retrieve sub_id from parameter with a nil fallback
    sub_id = params |> Map.get("sub_id", nil)
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end
```

Here i'm pattern matching on the `"main_id"` key and then retrieving the `sub_id` from the `params` variable.

The reason why you don't want to pattern match on both `main_id` and `sub_id` in the argument params is that, as you said, `sub_id` will only be present if the controller action is hit from a get request coming from the same index path.

Comment: If I write  `%{"main_id" => main_id} = params`, is that means `main_id` could be required parameter? I hope so.

Comment: Yes that means that the params have to match on `%{"main_id" => main_id}` all the complete params will be accessible via the variable `params`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your great advice!!

Comment: I'm still stacking. I have no idea how to write `route.ex` and redirect code. `conn |> redirect(to: index_path(conn, :index, main_id: main_id, sub_id: sub_id))`. However it cause error below. `protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for [main_id: "xxx", sub_id: "yyy"]. This protocol is implemented for: Any, Atom, BitString, Integer, Map`

Comment: @tajihiro I suggest you write another question to address this specific problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810311/what-is-the-difference-between-param-with-name-and-no-name-param-on-phoenix

Comment: Cannot this be achieved by using `when`?