# What is the difference between param with name and no name param on Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I write params like (A) and (B) in `router.ex`.

```
get "/index/:first/:second", IndexController, :index #(A)
get "/index/:first", IndexController, :index #(B)
```

which one should be collect (1) or (2)?

```
conn |>
  redirect(to: index_path(conn, :index, first: first, second: second)) #(1)

conn |>
  redirect(to: index_path(conn, :index, first, second: second)) #(2)
```

I have no idea of difference to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question but off the top of my head, I think, first, after connection and action name, you pass the named params and then, the last argument is the query string params, as far as I remember.

So for

```
get "/index/:first/:second", IndexController, :index #(A)
```

it should be

```
index_path(conn, :index, first, second)
```

or if you want some query params:

```
index_path(conn, :index, first, second, _format: "json")
```